# Change Particular route in MVC CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have below Url in my sample application in PHP MVC CI

```
http://localhost:1234/Sample/Index.php/User/index
```

Here User is `Controller` and index is `Action Method`

Can I write this url like below ?

```
http://localhost:1234/Users
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing your code , main mistake you have done you have renamed `index.php`, which is wrong, please revert that `index1212.php` to `index.php`

Rest of the thing you can follow other answers.But this is maon, codeigniter will not run without `index.php` file

**Edit**

One more error i noticed, in `routes.php`,

its

```
$route['Users'] = 'user/';
```

not `$routes`

And access your project like this,`http://localhost/Sample/Users`

And as far as my knowledge, you cannot hide folder name in url.

Comment: I think in `routes.php` i have removed `default_controller`, please add that as well.

Comment: did u rename your `index.php`??

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use custom routes. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

You do not need to include index.php in routes.php

```
// application > controllers > sample > Users.php filename first letter must be uppercase. Same with class name.
$routes['users'] = 'sample/users/index'; // Lower case preferred.

// When with out function would go straight to index function
$routes['users'] = 'sample/users'; 


// No Need for index.php
// $routes['Users'] = 'Sample/Index.php/User/index';
```

Now url will be

> `http://localhost:1234/project/users`
>
> `http://localhost/project/users`

Or with index.php

> `http://localhost:1234/project/index.php/users`
>
> `http://localhost/project/index.php/users`

You may need to remove index.php here are some htaccess

https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter

application > config > config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

htaccess example

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

## Note WAMP users:

If your using WAMP make sure you have rewrite module enabled.

Comment: sample is his folder name not a controller

Answer (score -1):

`Sample` is your project dir so you can not write the route which you want you can write the route as bellow.

> http://localhost:1234/Sample/Users

And your route file will look like bellow.

> $route['Users'] = 'User/index';